# display multiple select statements from same table side by side

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem is an **MYSQL** problem

I have four **select** statements which has names which is displayed below by below
I wanna show the **output** of that four **select** statements side by side
These four **select** statement values are derived from same **table**

**MySQL Code**

```
Select name from occupations
where occupation='Doctor'
order by name asc;

Select name from occupations
where occupation='Professor'
order by name asc;

Select name from occupations
where occupation='Singer'
order by name asc;

Select name from occupations
where occupation='Actor'
order by name asc;
```

The above code will display four columns below by below which will make it appear as if its a single column

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
Aamina
Julia
Priya
Ashley
Belvet
Britney
Maria
Meera
Naomi
Priyanka
Christeen
Jane
Jenny
Kristeen
Eve
Jennifer
Ketty
Samantha
```

My expected out put should be these names displaying in four columns side by side representing the select statements

**Note:** I have tried **googling** and **stackoverflow** and could not find a solution. I have found out a solution which is crazy large and completely different from my solution.
Kindly help me display the output side by side if you guys know

Comment: You should include the exact output you want to see here.

Comment: ok give me a second sir

Comment: Consider handling this requirement in your presentation layer e.g. PHP, rather than in MySQL.

Comment: Using sql for purely display formatting purposes is usually a bad idea. I second @TimBiegeleisen 's suggestion of handling the formatting part in you application logic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) as doctor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) as professor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) as singer,
       max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) as actor
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) as seqnum
      from occupations o
     ) o
group by seqnum
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And can you please explain the from part I am too much of a beginner @Gordon Lindoff

Comment: @writking . . . That is a subquery that assigns an incremental value to each occupation.  Just run the subquery separately to see what it does.